# copy/paste hotkey in windows linux subsystem Ubuntu terminal doesn't work?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

I installed windows linux subsystem Ubuntu 20.04 from microsoft store, but when I try to use ctrl-v for paste, or shift+arrow keys to select text in terminal, it won't work as expected. ctrl-v will show as '^V', `shift`+`arrow` keys will be D,C,A,B for left, right, up, down. I can't find the reason in the documents, the Edit menu of the terminal says paste is ctrl-v... but it doesn't work. [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD3BU.png) is what I get when I hit ctrl-v for three times, and shift+arrowkeys.

Does anybody know how to solve this? Thanks.

---

Following **harrymc**'s answer, I checked the *options* tab, it looks like this.
[image: 2]

there is no "Use Ctrl+Shift+C/V as Copy/Paste" but the "Enable Ctrl key shortcuts", which I checked and unchecked and checked again and nothing changed for the console.

Another thing to add, when I try to `ctrl`+`v` or `ctrl`+`shift`+`v`, the first time nothing will appear on screen, and the second time it shows "^V" in cmd line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ubuntu console uses by default the right-click mouse button as copy-paste:

- To paste, right-click anywhere in the console
- To copy, select the text and right-click.

If you wish to use the keyboard:

- Right-click the red icon on the top-left of the title bar
- Select Properties
- Go to the *Options* tab
- Check "Use Ctrl+Shift+C/V as Copy/Paste"
- Click OK
- The copy key is now
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
  while the paste key is
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.
  The right-click functionality is still available.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it didn't quite work. I edited the question to describe the results.

Comment: I have posted mine. One difference perhaps is that I had installed Ubuntu 18.04. Will try later in the day to install Ubuntu 20.04 to check if that's the reason.

Comment: Nope. The option is still there. Strange that you are missing this option. Perhaps something went wrong with your installation, so try to uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: One more detail: I'm using WSL1, are you on WSL2?

Comment: I am on WSL1. Will try uninstall and reinstall then. Thanks!

Comment: Reinstalled and still no option for ctrl+shift+c/v. I guess I'll stick with using the mouse click then...

Comment: That's weird. What is your version of Windows?

Comment: win10 Enterprise, ver 1803, OS build 17134.1610

Comment: Can't you upgrade to the latest version (offered by Windows Update, not downloaded)?

Comment: I have finished updating Windows (ver 1909 build 18363.959), now I have the shift+ctrl+c/v feature now! Thank you!